# How to register to Destination Wakfu 2?

Tags: wakfu

There is this big event coming this Friday on Wakfu, "Destination Wakfu 2".

On the video introducing the event and on the official forum post, they mention you need to register to the event by sending a screenshot of your newly created character, to a specific Discord channel.

**But I can't find that channel on their Discord server.**

How can I register myself for Destination Wakfu 2 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, the channel was hidden until the beginning of the event, on 21st of February.

One can register only from the beginning of the event.

Also, **it's possible to register until the end of the event !** (28th of February)